# Cannot read response headers for CORS request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

I have a working cross-domain web service call where I get my payload back, but I cannot read the headers in the response. Chrome can show me the headers in the request fine, but they are not available in jQuery's success handler.

```
var data_obj = { "userName": "myUser", "password": "000000" }

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://localhost:8443/AuthService.svc/auth',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data_obj),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
});
```

The only thing that gets logged to the console is:

> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Here is what Chrome is reporting for the OPTIONS and POST response headers, note that I am attempting to expose `Foo` and `Authorization` via `Acccess-Control-Expose-Headers`:

*OPTIONS*

```
Acccess-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Type, Foo, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Foo, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 20 Jul 2015 16:26:00 GMT
Foo:Bar
```

*POST*

```
Acccess-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Type, Foo, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Foo, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Authorization: custom_access_token = some_token
Content-Length:36
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 20 Jul 2015 16:26:00 GMT
Foo:Bar
```

Can anyone figure out why I can only access the `Content-Type` header in my success callback?

*Update*

Note I refactored the above to use `XMLHttpRequest`, the behaviour persists.

Comment: Both my OPTION and POST responses include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` if that's what you mean. And yes, I know that is bad practice :)

Comment: Yes, it is a CORS request, but I've amended my title for clarity.

Comment: Doh - amended that as well.

Comment: @hyphenbash That SO answer is three years old, refers to Firefox only (OP specified they were using Chrome for debugging), and the behavior described is not referenced on the jQuery site any more. Is there some other more recent reference that you are seeing?

Comment: Confirmed the same behaviour with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Is an options request part of a normal CORS request?

Comment: @hyphenbash I'm unsure how I would do a CORS request without the preflight... My understanding is the browser performs the preflight automatically when it detects you are making a cross domain request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a typo in your response header:

> Acccess-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Type, Foo, Authorization

You have three "c" in "access". I admit it took too long for me to notice too.

While I don't have Chrome (only Firefox), I replicated your request as closely as I could and fixing the typo returned this:

> Foo: Bar
>   Authorization: custom_access_token = some_token
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

### Addendum

Seeing that another answer is advising you to use `withCredentials`, if for some reason you did that, remember that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must match the `Origin` request header that your browser will likely set on its own and it can not be a wildcard. I'm putting this here to avoid another possible issue.

> The origin parameter specifies a URI that may access the resource.  The browser must enforce this.  For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource.

See the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: I answered because I think it is the issue. I wouldn't waste an answer otherwise.